# How to use Wildcard Search Parameterized?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, search, wildcard

```
public DataTable Search()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlCommand searchcommand = new SqlCommand(
        "Select * from [ITEM MASTER] WHERE Item_Description LIKE  '%' @Item_Description  '%' ", con);

    searchcommand.Parameters.Add("@Item_Description", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = search;
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(searchcommand);
    da.Fill(dt);
    return dt;
}
```

Here is my code. I need help on how to create a parameterized search using Object Oriented Programming

Comment: Looks like you're mostly just lacking concatenation operators between the parameter and the LIKE wildcards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short Answer

As Nathan said, just add `+` on either side of the `@Item_Description` parameter. This will [concatenate it together](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276862%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) with the rest of the command string.

```
SqlCommand searchcommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from [ITEM MASTER] WHERE Item_Description LIKE  '%' + @Item_Description + '%' ", con);
```

## More Advice

If you want to make your code slightly more readable, you can use the `@` to make a [verbatim string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). Among other things, the verbatim string lets us put a string onto multiple lines, like this:

```
SqlCommand searchcommand = new SqlCommand(
     @"Select * 
       from [ITEM MASTER] 
       WHERE Item_Description 
       LIKE  '%' + @Item_Description + '%' ", con);
```

For even more readability, you can put your string into its own variable, put the T-SQL keywords into all caps, and add a semicolon at the end of the command text, which would look like this...

## Final Code Sample

```
var commandText = @"

SELECT * 
FROM [ITEM MASTER] 
WHERE Item_Description 
LIKE  '%' + @Item_Description + '%';

";

SqlCommand searchcommand = new SqlCommand(commandText, con);
```

That's much nicer to read, in my opinion, when you next come across it in your maintenance work.